# Add listener to a group

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

How i can do something like this?  all the shapes in the group should not listen to the event, but the group should operate on the event, but do not work. I gave the example of the two groups, and they are actually very much, and so I have to add a listener to the layer, and listen to the babbling events all internal groups.

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 1000,
    height: 800
  });
  var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();


    var group1 =  new Kinetic.Group({listening: true});
    var group2 =  new Kinetic.Group();

    var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
        x: stage.getWidth() / 2,
        y: stage.getHeight() / 2,
        radius: 70,
        listening: false,
        fillLinearGradientStartPoint: {x:70, y:-70},
        fillLinearGradientEndPoint: {x:70,y:70},
        fillLinearGradientColorStops: [0, 'black', 1, 'white'],
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4
    });
    var circle2 = new Kinetic.Circle({
        x: 100,
        y: 100,
        radius: 70,
        listening: false,
        fillLinearGradientStartPoint: {x:70, y:-70},
        fillLinearGradientEndPoint: {x:70,y:70},
        fillLinearGradientColorStops: [0, 'black', 1, 'white'],

        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4
    });

    var circle3 = new Kinetic.Circle({
        x: 300,
        y: 300,
        radius: 70,
        listening: false,
        fillLinearGradientStartPoint: {x:70, y:-70},
        fillLinearGradientEndPoint: {x:70,y:70},
        fillLinearGradientColorStops: [0, '#678345', 1, '#824444'],
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4
    });
    var circle4 = new Kinetic.Circle({
        x: 200,
        y: 200,
        radius: 70,
        listening: false,
        fillLinearGradientStartPoint: {x:70, y:-70},
        fillLinearGradientEndPoint: {x:70,y:70},
        fillLinearGradientColorStops: [0, '#678345', 1, '#824444'],
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4
    });

   group1.add(circle);
   group1.add(circle2);

   group2.add(circle3);
   group2.add(circle4);




  // add the triangle shape to the layer
  layer.add(group1);
  layer.add(group2);

  layer.on("click",onClick);

  // add the layer to the stage
  stage.add(layer);

function onClick(e){
    console.log("click",e.target);

}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Only nodes in a group will trigger events

- your circles will trigger events
- clicking in a non-node area of a group will not trigger any events

A workaround is to add a transparent rect as a background covering the entire group width/height.

```
var group=new Kinetic.Group({
    x:0,y:0,width:100,height:100
})

var groupListener=new Kinetic.Rect({
    x:group.x(),
    y:group.y(),
    width:group.width(),
    height:group.height(),

});

group.add(groupListener);
```

Then you can assign a listener to the "invisible" groupListener rectangle

```
groupListener.on("click",function(){
    console.log("clicked on non-node area of group");
});
```

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/ur6be/